# Bevel is not symmetrical

Tags: modeling

I was trying to model a desk and came across a problem, I can't seem to solve.
I wanted to create a simple bevel.
I used `Mesh > Edges > Bevel` on a selected edge and got this result
[image: asymmetrical bevel]

Why is it not symmetrical? How can I make it symmetrical?

For reference, what I actually wanted: 
[image: symmetrical bevel]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It seems your object has non-uniform scale.  Apply the scale of the object with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *scale* to fix this problem.

Beveling with non-uniform scale:
[image]

Applying the scale:
[image]

Beveling after applying scale:
[image]

When you scale an object in object mode, it is not really "applied" to the object's geometry.  I like to think of scaling as a modifier that is always last in the stack, whatever you do in edit mode (or most other places) is as if it was done *before* the object was scaled.

Check out [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation) for more uses of applying scale.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you.
So applying scale/rotation/location is something like freeze transform in Maya. Good to know!