# Bevelling sharp interior corners

Tags: modeling

I am trying to model windows on a somewhat cylinder-shaped object and I cannot figure out how to satisfactorily bevel sharp interior corners of the areas around them.  A screenshot of what I am trying to do:

[image: Screenshot 1, before bevel]

And when I try to just use the bevel tool:

[image: Screenshot 2, after bevel]

I've also tried using the bevel weight modifier and selecting the edges I want to bevel, but it only seems to work up to those corners, even though they seem to bevel when the modifier is applied to the entire object:

[image: Screenshot 3, with bevel weight]

So basically, how would I go about doing this?

I'm a beginner so I apologize if there's something really important I've missed.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you [applied the scale](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23149/symetrical-bevel/23151#23151)?

Comment: @PGmath Yes, I tried that, but that didn't work either.. Thanks very much for the tip though.

Comment: Ngons.. remove doubles.. you can see the little useless faces hiding there n the viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a subdivision surface modifier, the easiest way to sharpen edges is with a loop cut and slide (Ctrl R)

[image]

This is where loop cut and slide is located
[image: This is where loop cut and slide is c]

And if that doesn't work try adding creases to the specific edges

[image]