# Rounding ends in rectangle

Tags: modeling, bevel

I have a problem with rounding rectangle. I know how to round a cube, but not how to evenly round a rectangular prism. When I use bevel, it does not seem to bevel evenly. But I want to do it correctly. Please see the following pictures for an example:

This is my model comparison. Here you can see my model is not rounded evenly.
[image: This is my model comparison. How you can see my model is not rounded evenly]

And this is standard cube, that you can see when program starts. It's rounded evenly, but when you will scale it, you can see, that it will round not evenly, like my model (But my model was created not on this method)
[image: beveled correctly]

Comment: I'm guessing you scaled the object in object mode to make it a rectangle? Does this help? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23149/symetrical-bevel/23151#23151

Comment: @RayMairlot, thanks, you're helped me :) David helped too. So closed

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try adding a support edge by ctrl+R in edit mode, edge like that should limit the area bevel is counted on and make to your liking :)
[image: Adding Support Edge to reduce bevel area]