# why I am not getting even inset?

Tags: modeling

I was trying to make the book in blender but when select 3 faces and trying to inset it evenly I got this that you can see in the picture.

in my inset option i have only select **offset even**

please help me...
[image: I am making a book and not geting even inset]

Comment: you must have scaled your object in Object mode, go back to Object mode and apply the scale (Ctrl A)

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23149/bevel-is-not-symmetrical