# Can I increase the bevel depth on one face but not on the other?

Tags: bevel

I'm not sure if I'm even using the correct terms for what I'm doing in adding a bevel, so please correct any incorrect terms or misunderstandings with this!

I have a cylinder and I've used a Boolean Modifier to remove an area in the center. I'm trying to bevel the edges there. Here's a screenshot of this, in Edit Mode, while I'm working on the bevel:
[image]

Note that the bevel reaches rather far (proportionally) from the edge and along the horizontal face, but it does not reach too far down the horizontal face. I'd like to extend the bevel farther down the vertical face and less on the horizontal one. I've experimented with the various settings in the Bevel Tool and have tried the Bevel Modifier as well, and I see the settings are almost the same there.

What can I do to extend the curve of the bevel down along the horizontal face?

NOTE: In case there's a better way to reach my goal, here's what I'm doing: I'm making dies to go in a pottery extruder. Think of the extruder like a caulk gun. Instead of a tip at the end, there's a die, and when you squeeze the handle, the clay comes out through the hole in the die. (It's a lot like the Play Dough extruder toy many of us have seen.) I've worked with some different dies with extruders and it seems that the clay that goes through an extruder die with a nice bevel around the hole comes out as less brittle than clay that goes through an extruder die with a more defined edge. I want more of a bevel because I think that'll make a positive difference.

Comment: I'm voting to close my own question. When I changed my search terms to include words about symmetry, I found the answer in a different question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23149/bevel-is-not-symmetrical

Comment: I had a bit of an answer.

Comment: Of course, it is your question!  You can just delete it. I think.

Comment: @common_goldfish If you're checking, I just tried paging you in chat.

Comment: Not sure how to chat.

Comment: @common_goldfish: Use this link - just use the text box at the bottom to write your messages. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm

Comment: @RobinBetts: Yes - see my first comment above. I did a VTC and that allowed someone to add an answer that provides other information here. (If I deleted it, then the answer here, which is also helpful, would not be available.)

Comment: @Tango apologies.. that comment automatically inserted when I was trying to help you close your own question ..:)

Comment: @RobinBetts: No problem. Glad you were trying to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have different bevel weights on different edges.

It is generally a good idea to apply scale with CTRL+A, before beveling because it may have an unintended result otherwise.

a.*In Edit Mode* You can select an edge, press **control B** and then drag inwards.  It will open a dialogue box.

[image]

b.*With Modifiers* The same action, can be completed non-destructively with a bevel modifier.  Select the edge, and then save it to a vertex group.  Add a bevel modifier and change the limit method to "Vertex Group", name the group in the Vertex group field.

[image]
[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: I'm going to skip deleting on my own, so you can get points on this answer. There's one other thing I found that helped: Scale. If the scale on vertical and horizontal are not the same, then the bevel won't be the same.

Comment: I see what you mean.  Good info.

Comment: Feel free to include that as a 2nd point in your answer if you want.